# How do I add space behind slash if space not contain behind slash?

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

Is that a way to find regex format something like that?

I may have a string or may be a list of line like

`Human have hands/fingers/feet and so on`

If space not contain behind slash, I want to add space behind slash `Human have hands/ fingers/ feet and so on`

But, if space contain behind string, I don't want to add extra space. Only want to add space on the rest of the string without space behind slash.

e.g `hands/fingers/ feet` to `hands/ fingers/ feet`

Comment: Please update your question `Human have hands/fingers/ feet`  and so on

Comment: Is this number of slashes always fixed (i.e. always two slashes)?

Comment: @LawrenceCherone Sorry, my fault. Updated it.

Comment: @Ibrahim it's not fixed number

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with this regex:

```
\/(\s)?
```

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/c67Mh9/1/

PHP example:

```
echo preg_replace('@\/(\s)?@', '/ ', "Human have hands/fingers/ feet and so on");
```

Comment: Ha ha. Very difficult to choose your answer and Shalitha Suranga answer. You guys doing great. I choose your answer. Because readable and a few code.

Comment: @KevinKyaw Glad you liked it. Hope it helps you.

Answer (score 1):

Below code can surely work (Tested Offline):

```
<?php
$string = "hands/fingers/feet";

$spaceArr = explode("/",$string);
$modify_string = '';
foreach($spaceArr as $val){
    $modify_string .= $val."/ ";    
}

echo $modify_string;
// Output is hands/ fingers/ feet

?>
```

You can add any much space in hands  /   fingers/   feet but output will always like hands/ fingers/ feet

Comment: Add any much space but it will remain same like hands/ fingers/ feet .  I have tested it offline at my end. It will work fine.

Comment: Puts a trailing slash, and space.

Comment: Sorry for confuse my question. This approach is nice. But, if I have a list of lines (may be around 50 lines of string), I have to loop every single line for this.

Comment: You just need to add it in one string $string whatever lines you are having, explode will modify your string and you can use it back.

Comment: actaully, if you use `implode('/ ', array_map('trim', $array))` you can skip the loop.

Comment: Yes you are right @ArtisticPhoenix then you use array_filter and 
 array_map. There are many logics behind it. I just answered the quickest and easiest one that comes in my mind.

Comment: `array_filter` is not needed.  Thanks for the idea though

Comment: Thank you indeed @ArtisticPhoenix Happy Coding!

Answer (score 1):

Yeah of course with RegEx for this one

```
$count = null;
$returnValue = preg_replace('/\\/([^ ])/', '/ $1', 'hands/fingers/ feet', -1, $count);
```

Explanation

`/\/([^ ])/` this regex matched `/` without space only and replace with '/ $1'. Here $1 is the character after `/`

See more : [https://en.functions-online.com/preg_replace.html?command={"pattern":"/\/([^ ])/","replacement":"/ $1","subject":"hands/fingers/ feet","limit":-1}](https://en.functions-online.com/preg_replace.html?command=%7B%22pattern%22:%22%5C/%5C%5C%5C/([%5E%20])%5C/%22,%22replacement%22:%22%5C/%20$1%22,%22subject%22:%22hands%5C/fingers%5C/%20feet%22,%22limit%22:-1%7D)

Comment: Ha didn't see your answer, I just deleted mine.

Comment: It's ok I found a better one.

Comment: @ArtisticPhoenix I saw your deleted answer too. Look great. Appreciate both of your help. But, I will choose Ibrahim answer. Because, it's clearly understand and very readable. Anyway, I upvoted your answer too. :) Hope you understand on that. :(

Comment: @KevinKyaw - nice comment, I just was updating my other answer to that effect.. You're on the right track, happy coding...

Answer (score 1):

Yes, using a negative look ahead is the best way.

```
$str = preg_replace('/\/(?!\s)/', '/ ', $str);
```

You can see it [here][1]

This uses a negative look ahead. So it  basically says:

Match the `/` only if it's not followed by a space.  Also look aheads don't consume any characters in the matching so there is no need to replace the letter if matching without a look ahead.

Special thanks to @ShalithaSuranga for posting the same answer I thought up originally, but before I had a chance to post it and thus forcing me to make a bit extra effort to use a look ahead.

I typically don't use them as they can be much more confusing then regular matching patterns.

That said, either one is probably going to be faster then explode or other more lengthy methods.  However, in this case speed may not be an issue, I would say go with the one that makes the most sense to you and is easier for you to Read and understand latter.

Readability is always #1, then functionality, then performance.

If you want a short non-regx answer you can use this too

```
$str = "hands/fingers/feet";
echo implode("/ ", array_map('trim', explode("/", $str)));
```

As seen [here](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/c05509a975601ba11e6653645533650bb28343e2)

For this one, `array_map` takes a function callback as the first argument, ( which can be a string ) and applies it or maps it to each item in an array.  In this case we want `trim` which removes whitespace from both sides of a string. Then we implode it back together.  This way an array like this from exploding `one/ two`

```
 [
    'one',
    ' two'
 ]
```

will have the whitespace trimmed off, then we implode it with the `'/ '` and all set.

Comment: Nice explanation. If I saw your answer before I'll mark down correct, I will surely choose your answer. Due to respect other peoples effort, I don't want to uncheck my acceptance answer. But, up vote and million thanks to you.

Comment: It's all good, I find it a relaxing distraction from my normal programming to do these little snippets.  Currently I am upgrading  4 wordpress sites, after locking them down with `.htaccess` ( deny php execution ). Then I have about 200 files or so to go through that have been corrupted by a defunct Joomla site that "Was" on this server.  Fun stuff....

Comment: I always over explain things, at work I run a small team of junior developers, they are quite capable. A few I can see even surpassing me in time.  They are "good students"  but I think it makes me think of being like a "teacher" or "mentor" to much ... lol

Answer (score 0):

Use  `explode()` OR try the `str_replace()` example below

Please try `str_replace()`:

```
<php
$words = 'hands/fingers/ feet'; /** Your example words **/
$words = str_replace('/', '/ ', $words); /** Replace any slash with a slash AND a space **/
$words = str_replace('/  ', '/ ', $words); /** Replace slash with 2 spaces with slash with 1 space as this is what you need **/

echo $words; /** Output: hands/ fingers/ feet **/
?>
```

I hope this will bring you into the right direction..